# dropdown menu not operate after modal open(remote)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

dropdown menu not operate after modal open(remote)

However, if i open modal once again to work dropdown menu again.
bootstrap version is 3.3.6(latest version)

and general modal opening is not problem. only remote method modal opening is problem.

this is my html code

```js
function openModal(review_id)
{
  $("#myModal").modal({
    remote: '/review'
  });
}
```

```html
<!-- dropdown menu section -->
<div class="gnb-section" style="width: 1440px; margin: auto">
  <ul class="gnb">
    <li class="dropdown main{{ main_active }}" role="menu">
      {% if topic == "IT" %}
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">GET IT REVIEW</a>
      {%  endif %}
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="badge pull-right">2</span>menu1-1</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="badge pull-right">2</span>menu1-2</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="badge pull-right">2</span>menu1-3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="search{{ search_active }}"><a href="/review/search/">menu2</a></li>
    <li>menu3</li>
    <li class="write{{ review_active }}"><a href="/review/write/">menu4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>


<!-- modal open section... -->

<a href="#" onclick="openModal(8)">
  <div class="panel panel-default sq sec1">
    <div class="pannel-body">
      <div class="pnl-sec1">
      </div>
      <div class="pnl-sec2">
        contetns
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
                            
                   
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it looks like duplicate header.html

not the bootstrap bug.

check that